# Android Studio is telling me it cannot resolve Toast.show

Tags: android

I put:

```
Toast.makeText(
    FunFactsActivity.this,
    "Yay!",
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

and Android Studio is telling:

> Cannot resolve method 'show()'

the code is with a red  below.

Comment: Can you share your hole code where you use ´Toast´?

Comment: post full code. there may be problem in the class not the Toast.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help, but I was having the same problem and rather than typing out the code myself, I started typing "Toast" and clicked on the suggestion for make a new toast, and it accepted it without the error. I was missing a parentheses I didn't notice though.

Comment: This is not a good answer because it is very specific to your case

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to Toast your text in the FunFactsActivity then do this:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your text", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: An Activity is a Context... How does this help?

Comment: Maybe, some people doesn't extend Activity. I'm not look full him code

Comment: The specific error "cannot resolve method show()", is not fixed by this solution, though